# Meaning of the word Duhkkhanta?

Tags: pashupata-shaivism

In the Pasupata Sutram are quoted  five doctrinal elements, one of them is Duhkkhanta:

> Pasupati is the only cause and He grants us His grace directlyin the
> share of *duhkkhanta*

What is the precise meaning of the word Duhkkhanta?

Comment: Ideally means ending of dukh or sorrow. He grants grace directly in the share of ending sorrow? You can possibly put the original verse too

Comment: Thanks, that was the original verse i will add references

Comment: The original verse was in English?

Comment: yes i don’t have in other sources

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[You **MUST** cite the source for the quote of the block quoted verse in *your question*.]

The word,
duḥkhānta ( दुखांत) literally means
***duḥkh*** [दुःख (sorrow)] + ***ānta*** [अंत (end)]  = End of Sorrow.

The sorrow can both have spiritual and material implications although.

In spiritual and metaphysical connotation, the end of sorrow will innately mean freedom from the mundane cycle of wordly existence (samsara), संसार), i.e. Moksha (मोक्ष).

Etymologically, ***duḥkhānta*** (दुखांत)  *is* *one of the five doctrinal elements or principles*  which forms the core credal based philosophical crux of the ***[Pāśupata Sect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pashupata_Shaivism)*** ( पाशुपत सम्प्रदाय ).

The [five doctrinal elements](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=trh9DwAAQBAJ&pg=PT93&dq=Pashupata%20dukhanta&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjD1dTx44zvAhXFgeYKHfl7DNwQ6AEwBHoECAMQAw#v=onepage&q=Pashupata%20dukhanta&f=false) being,

> ***karya*** (कार्य)  i.e. Effect
>
> ***kāraṇa*** (कारण )  i.e. Cause
>
> ***yoga*** (योग )  i.e. Union or Contact
>
> ***vidhi*** (विधि )  i.e. Behavior
>
> ***duḥkhānta*** (दुखांत )  i.e. End of Sorrow(s), Moksha (मोक्ष)

Thus, the doctrine proclaims that

> The sorrow can be removed by the grace of Shiva (शिव), who is *Pashupati* (पशुपति), the lord and protector of all.
> Liberation **cannot** be obtained by
> *jñāna* (ज्ञान) - knowledge,
> neither *vairāgya* (वैराग्यं) - Detachment,
> nor *dharma* (धर्म) - Righteous conduct,
> and neither  *aiśvarya-tyāga* (ऐश्वर्य-त्याग) - Surrendering Opulences.
> Only through *Shivas* grace may one attain the final liberation.  And thus,  **दुखांतक - duḥkhāntaka** ( i.e., the one who ends sorrows); being one of Shivas' several names.

Furthermore, *duḥkhānta*  itself  being of [two types](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=8RSzDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA12&dq=%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%96%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%A4%20shiva&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjCuYaG34zvAhWa7XMBHf9hCjEQ6AEwAXoECAIQAw#v=onepage&q=%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%96%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%82%E0%A4%A4%20shiva&f=false) :-

[image: Classification of duḥkhānta]

*A snippet of the above linked book, explaining the two types of duḥkhānta*.

*I couldn't find any free English version for this,  here is paraphrased Translation of the yellow highlighted paragraph :-*

> Liberation (मुक्ति) achieved after attaining freedom from *duḥkha*
> (sorrows) is known as  duḥkhānta (दुखांत). Due to  *False knowledge*
> (मिथ्या ज्ञान ), *Unrighteous Conduct* (अधर्म), *Individuals'
> Consciousness '* (चित्त) *aversion* (विमुख) *towards the Supreme
> Consciousness* (Shiva),    and *ignorance* (अल्पज्ञता)  are the
> primary reasons for the attachment of the individual in the samsara.
> Detachment from *samsaraic* ties is a prerequisite to gain Shivas'
> Grace. To achieve detachment, *sādhnā yoga* (साधना योग) and
> *prapatti* (प्रपत्ति) is imperative.
>
> *Duḥkhānta* (दुखांत) is of  ***Sātmaka*** (सात्मक) and ***Anātmaka*** (अनात्मक) types.
>
> In the ***Sātmaka Duḥkhānta (सात्मक दुखांत)***, through the powers of -
> *jñāna* (ज्ञान) - Knowledge,  and,   *dharma* (धर्म) - Righteous conduct, the individual achieves Youthful Opulences,(**?**) ( युवा
> ऐश्वर्य **?**).
>
> In the ***Anātmaka Duḥkhānta  (अनात्मक दुखांत)***, there is complete
> unequivocal decay/annihilation (छय/क्षय - kṣaya) of all kinds of
> sorrows (Duḥkha).
>
> Philosophical views - *darśana*(दर्शन);  Listening - *śravaṇa*
> (श्रवण) ;  Thinking - *manana* (मनन) ;   Wisdom sciences - *vijñāna*
> (विज्ञान)  and  Omniscience - *sarvajñatva*  (सर्वज्ञत्व) , are
> collectively called as the **five limbs of  *jñāna*** (ज्ञान) -
> Knowledge.  The *Pāśupata Sect*, thus, recommends the above mentioned
> extraordinary and remarkable practices as the ultimate way to achieve
> the Supreme position (of Moksha - मोक्ष).

Comment: I was reading the Pashupata Sutram Indeed. Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

> Meaning of the word Duhkkhanta?

[दुःख](https://sanskritdictionary.com/du%E1%B8%A5kha/102346/1) (duhkha) = sorrow
[अन्त](https://sanskritdictionary.com/anta/9364/1) (anta) = end

So, [दुःखान्त​](https://sanskritdictionary.com/du%E1%B8%A5kh%C4%81nta/102418/1) (duhkhAnta) = end of sorrow.

It means end of samsara, which is the cause of grief. And the ending of samsara means moksha (liberation).

So it is saying Pashupati gives moksha.